# Using the last valid data index in one Dataframe to select data in another Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, indexing

### I want to find the last valid index of the first Dataframe, and use it to index the second Dataframe.

So, suppose I have the following Dataframe (df1):

```
            Site 1  Site 2  Site 3  Site 4  Site 5  Site 6
Date                                                      
2000-01-01    13.0    28.0    76.0      45    90.0    58.0
2001-01-01    77.0    75.0    57.0       3    41.0    24.0
2002-01-01    50.0    29.0     2.0      65    48.0    21.0
2003-01-01     7.0    48.0    14.0      63    12.0    66.0
2004-01-01    11.0    90.0    11.0       5    47.0     6.0
2005-01-01    50.0     4.0    31.0       1    40.0    79.0
2006-01-01    30.0    98.0    91.0      96    43.0    39.0
2007-01-01    50.0    20.0    54.0      65     NaN    47.0
2008-01-01    24.0    84.0    52.0      84     NaN    81.0
2009-01-01    56.0    61.0    57.0      25     NaN    36.0
2010-01-01    87.0    45.0    68.0      65     NaN    71.0
2011-01-01    22.0    50.0    92.0      91     NaN    48.0
2012-01-01    12.0    44.0    79.0      77     NaN    25.0
2013-01-01     1.0    22.0    34.0      57     NaN    25.0
2014-01-01    94.0     NaN    86.0      97     NaN    91.0
2015-01-01     2.0     NaN    98.0      44     NaN    79.0
2016-01-01    81.0     NaN    35.0      87     NaN    32.0
2017-01-01    59.0     NaN    95.0      32     NaN    58.0
2018-01-01     NaN     NaN     3.0      14     NaN     NaN
2019-01-01     NaN     NaN    48.0       9     NaN     NaN
2020-01-01     NaN     NaN     NaN      49     NaN     NaN
```

Now I can use "first_valid_index()" to find the last valid index of each column:

```
lvi = df.apply(lambda series: series.last_valid_index())
```

Which yields:

```
Site 1   2017-01-01
Site 2   2013-01-01
Site 3   2019-01-01
Site 4   2020-01-01
Site 5   2006-01-01
Site 6   2017-01-01
```

How do I apply this to another Dataframe where I use this index to slice the timeseries of another Dataframe.  Another example of a Dataframe could be created with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import random

random.seed(30)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Site 1": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 2": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 3": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 4": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 5": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 6": np.random.rand(21)})

idx = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2020-01-01',freq ='AS')
df2 = df2.set_index(idx)
```

How do I use that "lvi" variable to index into df2?

To do this manually I could just use:

```
df_s1 = df['Site 1'].loc['2000-01-01':'2017-01-01']
```

To get something like:

```
2000-01-01    13.0
2001-01-01    77.0
2002-01-01    50.0
2003-01-01     7.0
2004-01-01    11.0
2005-01-01    50.0
2006-01-01    30.0
2007-01-01    50.0
2008-01-01    24.0
2009-01-01    56.0
2010-01-01    87.0
2011-01-01    22.0
2012-01-01    12.0
2013-01-01     1.0
2014-01-01    94.0
2015-01-01     2.0
2016-01-01    81.0
2017-01-01    59.0
```

Is there a better way to approach this?  Also, will each column have to essentially be its own dataframe to work?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: isn't as simple as `df.index.max()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after thinking about this for a while and trying to come up with a detailed procedure that involved a for loop etc., I came to the conclusions that this simple math operation will do the trick.  Basically I am taking advantage of how math is done between Dataframes in pandas.

```
output = df1*0 + df2
```

This gives the output on df2 that will take on the NaN values from df1 and look like this:

```
              Site 1    Site 2    Site 3    Site 4    Site 5    Site 6
Date                                                                  
2000-01-01  0.690597  0.443933  0.787931  0.659639  0.363606  0.922373
2001-01-01  0.388669  0.577734  0.450225  0.021592  0.554249  0.305546
2002-01-01  0.578212  0.927848  0.361426  0.840541  0.626881  0.545491
2003-01-01  0.431668  0.128282  0.893351  0.783488  0.122182  0.666194
2004-01-01  0.151491  0.928584  0.834474  0.945401  0.590830  0.802648
2005-01-01  0.113477  0.398326  0.649955  0.202538  0.485927  0.127925
2006-01-01  0.521906  0.458672  0.923632  0.948696  0.638754  0.552753
2007-01-01  0.266599  0.839047  0.099069  0.000928       NaN  0.018146
2008-01-01  0.819810  0.809779  0.706223  0.247780       NaN  0.759691
2009-01-01  0.441574  0.020291  0.702551  0.468862       NaN  0.341191
2010-01-01  0.277030  0.130573  0.906697  0.589474       NaN  0.819986
2011-01-01  0.795344  0.103121  0.846405  0.589916       NaN  0.564411
2012-01-01  0.697255  0.599767  0.206482  0.718980       NaN  0.731366
2013-01-01  0.891771  0.001944  0.703132  0.751986       NaN  0.845933
2014-01-01  0.672579       NaN  0.466981  0.466770       NaN  0.618069
2015-01-01  0.767219       NaN  0.702156  0.370905       NaN  0.481971
2016-01-01  0.315264       NaN  0.793531  0.754920       NaN  0.091432
2017-01-01  0.431651       NaN  0.974520  0.708074       NaN  0.870077
2018-01-01       NaN       NaN  0.408743  0.430576       NaN       NaN
2019-01-01       NaN       NaN  0.751509  0.755521       NaN       NaN
2020-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.518533       NaN       NaN
```

I was basically wanting to imprint the NaN values from one Dataframe onto another.  I cannot believe how difficult I was making this. As long as my Dataframes are the same size this should work fine for my needs.

Now I should be able to take it from here to calculate the percent change from each last valid datapoint. Thank you everyone for the input!

### EDIT:

Just to show everyone what I was ultimately trying to accomplish, here is the final code I produced with everyone's help and suggestions!

The original df originally looked like:

```
            Site 1  Site 2  Site 3  Site 4  Site 5  Site 6
Date                                                      
2000-01-01    13.0    28.0    76.0      45    90.0    58.0
2001-01-01    77.0    75.0    57.0       3    41.0    24.0
2002-01-01    50.0    29.0     2.0      65    48.0    21.0
2003-01-01     7.0    48.0    14.0      63    12.0    66.0
2004-01-01    11.0    90.0    11.0       5    47.0     6.0
2005-01-01    50.0     4.0    31.0       1    40.0    79.0
2006-01-01    30.0    98.0    91.0      96    43.0    39.0
2007-01-01    50.0    20.0    54.0      65     NaN    47.0
2008-01-01    24.0    84.0    52.0      84     NaN    81.0
2009-01-01    56.0    61.0    57.0      25     NaN    36.0
2010-01-01    87.0    45.0    68.0      65     NaN    71.0
2011-01-01    22.0    50.0    92.0      91     NaN    48.0
2012-01-01    12.0    44.0    79.0      77     NaN    25.0
2013-01-01     1.0    22.0    34.0      57     NaN    25.0
2014-01-01    94.0     NaN    86.0      97     NaN    91.0
2015-01-01     2.0     NaN    98.0      44     NaN    79.0
2016-01-01    81.0     NaN    35.0      87     NaN    32.0
2017-01-01    59.0     NaN    95.0      32     NaN    58.0
2018-01-01     NaN     NaN     3.0      14     NaN     NaN
2019-01-01     NaN     NaN    48.0       9     NaN     NaN
2020-01-01     NaN     NaN     NaN      49     NaN     NaN
```

Then I came up with a second full dataframe (df2) with:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Site 1": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 2": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 3": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 4": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 5": np.random.rand(21),
    "Site 6": np.random.rand(21)})
idx = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2020-01-01',freq ='AS')
df2 = df2.set_index(idx)
```

Now I replace the nan values in df2 with the nan values from df:

```
dfr = df2[df.notna()]
```

Then I invert the dataframe:

```
dfr = dfr[::-1]

valid_first = dfr.apply(lambda col: col.first_valid_index())
valid_last = dfr.apply(lambda col: col.last_valid_index())
```

Now I want the to calculate the percent change from my last valid data point, which is fixed for each column.  This gives me the % change from the present to the past, with respect to the most recent (or last valid) data point.

```
new = []
for j in dfr:
    m = dfr[j].loc[valid_first[j]:valid_last[j]]
    pc = m / m.iloc[0]-1
    new.append(pc)

final = pd.concat(new,axis=1)    
print(final)
```

Which gave me:

```
              Site 1    Site 2    Site 3    Site 4     Site 5    Site 6
2000-01-01  0.270209 -0.728445 -0.636105  0.380330  41.339081 -0.462147
2001-01-01  0.854952 -0.827804 -0.703568 -0.787391  40.588791 -0.884806
2002-01-01 -0.677757 -0.120482 -0.208255 -0.982097  54.348094 -0.483415
2003-01-01 -0.322010 -0.061277 -0.382602  1.025088   5.440808 -0.602661
2004-01-01  1.574451 -0.768251 -0.543260  1.210434  50.494788 -0.859331
2005-01-01 -0.412226 -0.866441 -0.055027 -0.168267   1.346869 -0.385080
2006-01-01  1.280867 -0.640899  0.354513  1.086703   0.000000  0.108504
2007-01-01  1.121585 -0.741675 -0.735990 -0.768578        NaN -0.119436
2008-01-01 -0.210467 -0.376884 -0.575106 -0.779147        NaN  0.055949
2009-01-01  1.864107 -0.966827  0.566590  1.003121        NaN -0.214482
2010-01-01  0.571762 -0.311459 -0.518113  1.036950        NaN -0.513911
2011-01-01 -0.122525 -0.178137 -0.641642  0.197481        NaN  0.033141
2012-01-01  0.403578 -0.829402  0.161753 -0.438578        NaN -0.996595
2013-01-01  0.383481  0.000000 -0.305824  0.602079        NaN -0.057711
2014-01-01 -0.699708       NaN -0.515074 -0.277157        NaN -0.840873
2015-01-01  0.422364       NaN -0.759708  1.230037        NaN -0.663253
2016-01-01 -0.418945       NaN  0.197396 -0.445260        NaN -0.299741
2017-01-01  0.000000       NaN -0.897428  0.669791        NaN  0.000000
2018-01-01       NaN       NaN  0.138997  0.486961        NaN       NaN
2019-01-01       NaN       NaN  0.000000  0.200771        NaN       NaN
2020-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.000000        NaN       NaN
```

I know often times these questions don't have context, so here is the final output achieved thanks to your input.  Again, thank you to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit more idiomatic:

```
df2[df.notna()]
```

or even

```
df2.where(df.notna())
```

Note that in these cases (and `df1*0 + df2`), the operations are done for matching index values of `df` and `df2`.  For example, `df2[df.reset_index(drop=True).notna()]` will return all `nan` because there are no common index values.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for this!  I am a bit new to Python so tips about my code being more idiomatic is definitely welcome!

Comment: your solution will also be performant, hopefully this is a little easier to understand the intent :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine:

```
In [34]: d
Out[34]: 
      x    y
Date                
2020-01-01  1.0  2.0
2020-01-02  1.0  2.0
2020-01-03  1.0  2.0
2020-01-04  1.0  2.0
2020-01-05  1.0  2.0
2020-01-06  1.0  NaN
2020-01-07  1.0  NaN
2020-01-08  1.0  NaN
2020-01-09  1.0  NaN
2020-01-10  1.0  NaN
2020-01-11  NaN  NaN
2020-01-12  NaN  NaN
2020-01-13  NaN  NaN
2020-01-14  NaN  NaN
2020-01-15  NaN  NaN
2020-01-16  NaN  NaN
2020-01-17  NaN  NaN
2020-01-18  NaN  NaN
2020-01-19  NaN  NaN
2020-01-20  NaN  NaN

In [35]: d.apply(lambda col: col.last_valid_index())
Out[35]: 
x   2020-01-10
y   2020-01-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And then:
`In [15]: d.apply(lambda col: col.last_valid_index()).apply(lambda date: df2.loc[date])                                                                   Out[15]:  z x  0.940396 y  0.564007`

Comment: Hey Robby, thank you for the answer.  So now that you are at this step, the other part of my question was how do you apply the last_valid_index values you got here to another dataframe? So imagine you have another dataframe (df2) with x2 and y2 that are have valid data at all times over the same timespan.  I only want the data in df2 to reflect data until the last valid index of df1.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I added a part to deal with that. Just another `apply`, and using the `.loc[]` functionality.

Comment: Hey Robby, thank you for the feedback.  I was hoping the output would be slice of df2.  So in my example my expected output goes from 2000-2017 (given by df['Site 1'].loc['2000-01-01':'2017-01-01'])  Just so you have some more context on the point of this exercise: I am taking that last valid index and I am going to calculate the % change back in time from the last valid datapoint for each column in df2.  I am ultimately trying to rectify the differences between when the data ends in each column of df1 and projecting them onto df2 to get my % changes.  I hope that makes some sense...

Comment: I think you're off to a good start. There are always several ways to do this kind of thing in Pandas.

Comment: Good deal, I appreciate the help Robby!